# React Navigation 5 Drawer initialRouteName not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

I am using React Navigation 5 with React Native. I have a drawer with two screen each is a stack navigator by itself. My setup is as follows:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  initialRouteName='Balance'
  drawerType='slide'
  drawerContentOptions={drawerOption}
  drawerContent={drawerContent}
   
>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name='Home'
    component={UserStackScreen}
  />
  <Drawer.Screen name='Balance' component={BalanceStackScreen} />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

When i load the app i am routed to the home screen not to the balance screen although my  initialRouteName='Balance'
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There was nothing wrong with my setup. I just was routing to the User page directly from another Login screen.

Answer (score 0):

In React Navigation 5, the initialRouteName prop is not supported directly on the Drawer.Navigator component. Instead, you can achieve the desired behavior by setting the initialRoute prop on the Drawer.Screen component.

Here's an updated version of your code:

```js
<Drawer.Navigator
  drawerType="slide"
  drawerContentOptions={drawerOption}
  drawerContent={drawerContent}
>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={UserStackScreen} />
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="Balance"
    component={BalanceStackScreen}
    initialParams={{ initialRoute: true }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

In this example, I've added the initialParams prop to the "Balance" screen and set its value to { initialRoute: true }. You can pass any other parameters as needed. Then, inside your BalanceStackScreen component, you can access the initialRoute parameter in the screen's props to determine if it should be the initial route.

Make sure to update your BalanceStackScreen component to handle the initialRoute prop accordingly:

```js
const BalanceStackScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  // Use route.params.initialRoute to determine if it's the initial route
  const isInitialRoute = route.params?.initialRoute;

  // Rest of your code

  return (
    // Your component JSX
  );
};
```

By passing the initialParams to the desired screen and accessing it inside the component, you can control the initial route in React Navigation 5's Drawer Navigator.